# Two independent events, $A$ and $B$; find $B$ given only $A$ and $A\cup B$

Tags: probability

Sorry to be a burden but my maths exam is tomorrow and I have no idea how to do this at all. Here is the exact question :

The two independent events $A$ and $B$ are such that
$P(A) = 0.2$, $P(A\cup B) = 0.4 $.

- a. Evaluate $P(B)$.
- b. Find the probability that at least one of the two events occurs.
- c. Given that exactly one of the events occurs, find the probability that $A$ occurs.

I need help with the entire question really, but at least part a.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the _definition_ of independent events?  What is $P(A \cup B)$ in terms of $P(A)$, $P(B)$, etc?  Is it true that $x - xy = x(1-y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers?

Comment: (b) is $P(A \cup B)$.  (c) is $\dfrac{P(A)-P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cup B) -P(A \cap B)}$

Comment: @Dilip.  I think not.  It could be $P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ where $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

Comment: But if I don't know what P(ANB) is, how do I work it out? I'm probably missing something really simple here, but I simply don't understand :(

Comment: @PaulRace: $0.4 = 0.2+P(B)-0.2 \cdot P(B)$. Solve for $P(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

**(a)** The fact that
$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
is useful, and the fact that in this case, by independence, we have $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$
Let $P(B)=y$.  Then 
$$0.4=0.2+y -(0.2)y.$$
The above equation is linear in $y$, and easy to solve. We get $y=0.25$.

**(b)** A peculiar question! This asks for $P(A \cup B)$, but we have been told that this is $0.4$.

**(c)** You are probably expected to use the defining formula for conditional probability, namely that 
$$P(C|D)=\frac{P(C\cap D)}{P(D)}. \qquad(\ast)$$
In our problem, $C$ is the event $A$, and $D$ is the event "exactly one of $A$ and $B$."

First we find $P(D)$.  The probability that exactly one of $A$ and $B$ occurs is $P(A \cup B)$ minus the probability that $A$ and $B$ *both* occur.  But since $P(A)=0.2$ and $P(B)=0.25$, by independence $P(A  \cap B)=(0.2)(0.25)=0.05$.  It follows that the probability that exactly one of $A$ and $B$ occurs is $0.4-0.05$, which is $0.35$.

Now we need $P(C \cap D)$, the probability that $A$ occurs and exactly one of $A$ and $B$ occurs. This is a long-winded way of saying that $A$ occurs and $B$ does not. We have  $P(A)=0.2$. By our earlier computation, $P(B)=0.25$, so $P(B^c)$ (the probability $B$ does not occur) is $0.75$. By independence, $P(A \cap B^c)=(0.2)(0.75)=0.15$.

Substituting in $(\ast)$, we find that the probability that $A$ occurs given that exactly one of $A$ and $B$ occurs is $\dfrac{0.15}{0.35}$, which looks better as the fraction $2/7$.